# Why photoshop SDK sample code don‘t work in my Mac-OS10.7？

Tags: photoshop

I used the photoshop SDK CS5. And complied the sample code hidden in the filter folder with my x-code. And I get the target file 'Hidden.plugin' . But it seems no use, when I puts it to the photoshop plug-ins plugin folder.The version of my photoshop is also CS5. Anyone can tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with the help of others in other website.
http://forums.adobe.com/message/5802597#5802597